# OneNote: Import data from other sources?

Tags: import, microsoft-onenote, evernote

**In MS OneNote, is it possible to import data from other sources?**

(Like Google notebook,  Evernote, etc?)

If so, what are the steps to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the version of OneNote.  For 2007, you can ["print" into OneNote](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830047).  There isn't any import functionality for 2003, though.